# C++ Boost graph libary Add_vertex with custom properties and check for redundancy

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I want to create a boost graph from a GeoJSON file containg a network of linestrings. Some linestrings have common nodes. In other words: everything is somehow connected.
the file looks like this: (here only 3 linestrings: in reality more than 8000).

```
{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"id": 1}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 147.0, -4.8 ], [ 141.0, -2.0 ] ]}},
{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"id": 2}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 152.6, -5.2 ], [ 152.05, -3.8 ], [ 147.0, -4.8 ] ] } },
{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"id": 3}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 147.0, -4.8 ], [ 144.73, 0.0 ] ] } },
```

You see that the coordinate [147.0, -4.8] is part of all 3 linestrings.

I iterate over this file and save these information in a vector linestrings containing struct variables called linestring:

```
struct linestring //data of one linestring
{
    int id;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> pos; //2D vector conatining x and y positions
};
std::vector <linestring> linestrings; //containing the inforamtion of all linestrings
```

Now I want to use this to build a boost graph:

```
struct Nodes
{
    double x;
    double y;
};
struct Legs
{
    int id;
    double distance; 
    //edge weight calculated with distance=sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2) euclidean distance

};

typedef adjacency_list<listS, vecS, undirectedS, Nodes, Legs> graph_t;
graph_t LinestringGraph;
```

Which commands are recommended for such a job?

I don't want to add all vertexes and check for redundancy by iterating or other time consuming stuff.

Is there a possibility to add an edge with the custom id and the calculated edge weight together with the vertexes containing the custom property of xy-coordinate.

I want to do something like this:
PSEUDOCODE:

```
iterate over the vector linestrings
count the number of waypoints in the linestring
//e.g. in id=2 are "coordinates": 
// [ [ 152.6, -5.2 ], [ 152.05, -3.8 ], [ 147.0, -4.8 ] ]
//edge from [ 152.6, -5.2 ] to [ 152.05, -3.8 ] 
// and from  [ 152.05, -3.8 ] to [ 147.0, -4.8 ]
add counted edges to the boost graph 
   and weight with euclidean distance of start and end coordinate of 
   the current (part)linestring.
if one vertex already exists (e.g. [ 147.0, -4.8 ]) 
    do not create a new vertex --> use the existing
```

######################################
AFTER the very helpful answer of @sehe and @ravenspoint (Thank you for the very quick reply. I never expect such help) I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>

using namespace boost;

struct point  // single point/node
{
    double lon, lat; //not yet x, y because I want to use longitude and latitude
    auto operator==(const point &other) 
    {
        return abs(this->lon - other.lon)< 0.000000000001 
               && abs(this->lat - other.lat < 0.000000000001;
    } 
//thanks for the operator hint from @sehe
};

struct Legs
{
    int id;
    double Distance;  // edge weight
};

struct linestring  // data of single linestring
{
    int id;
    std::vector<point> coords;  // vector with double lon/lat
};

using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
                                point, Legs>;
using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
using E = G::edge_descriptor;

int main()
{
    std::vector<linestring> linestrings;  // vector with all linestrings
    //some not relevant code for this question: reading in the JSON file with poco
    //everything is now stored in the vector linestrings
    //you can acess it in the following way:
    for (linestring i : linestrings)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "id: " << i.id << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Number of waypoints: " 
                  << i.coords.size() << " \nwaypoints are: (lon, lat): ";
        for (point waypoint : i.coords)
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << "(" << waypoint.lon << ", " << waypoint.lat << ")";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::map<point, V> mapping;
    for (auto &f : linestrings)
    {
        for (auto &p : f.coords)
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << p.lon << ", " << p.lat << std::endl;
            if (auto it = mapping.find(p); it == mapping.end())
            {
                mapping.emplace(p, add_vertex(p, g));
            }
        }
    };
    return 0;
}
```

With this I get the error:
error C2678: binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
I tried instead of operator== the operator< but still same result/error

after the line from @sehe

```
int next_edge_id = 0;
```

I don't understand how to proceed and add the edges to the graph according to a linestring in the linestrings vector.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to add all vertexes and check for redundancy by iterating
> or other time consuming stuff.

Iterating is how computers accomplish stuff.  The STL containers help you do it fast and efficiently, with very few lines of code.  Like this:

```
void cVertex::indexer(std::vector<cVertex>& vertexVector)
{
    auto it = std::find(
        vertexVector.begin(),
        vertexVector.end(),
        *this);
    if (it == vertexVector.end())
    {
        // new unique vertex
        myIndex = vertexVector.size();
        vertexVector.push_back(*this);
    }
    else
    {
        // duplicate vertex
        myIndex = it->myIndex;
    }
}

void cSolution::indexUniqueVertices()
{
     std::vector<cVertex> vertexVector;

    // loop over all line strings
    for (auto &l : myLineString)
    {
        // loop over edges in line string
        for (auto &e : l.myEdge)
        {
            // index the vertices
            e.v1.indexer(vertexVector);
            e.v2.indexer(vertexVector);
        }
    }
```

Output is

```
unique vertices
0 (147 -4.8)
1 (141 -2)
2 (152.6 -5.2)
3 (152.05 -3.8)
4 (144.73 0)

{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"id": 1}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", 
"coordinates": [ [ 147.0, -4.8 ], [ 141.0, -2.0 ] ]}}
has edges:
0 (147 -4.8) to 1 (141 -2)

{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"id": 2}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", 
"coordinates": [ [ 152.6, -5.2 ], [ 152.05, -3.8 ], [ 147.0, -4.8 ] ] } }
has edges:
2 (152.6 -5.2) to 3 (152.05 -3.8)
3 (152.05 -3.8) to 0 (147 -4.8)

{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"id": 3}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", 
"coordinates": [ [ 147.0, -4.8 ], [ 144.73, 0.0 ] ] } }
has edges:
0 (147 -4.8) to 4 (144.73 0)
```

Code for the complete application at https://github.com/JamesBremner/GeoJSONtoGraph/blob/main/src/main.cpp

**PERFORMANCE**

This code can handle 10,000 vertices in 0.1 second.

Most of the time is spent searching through the vector checking for a redundant node.  Here is the detailed timing profile

```
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
      1        0.098734        0.098734        vector
  20008        4.79804e-06     0.0959992       vector find
```

I thought that using a set, which uses a binary search, might be faster at the cost of some extra  code complexity.

```
Calls           Mean (secs)     Total           Scope
       1        3.19261         3.19261         set
   20008        0.00015777      3.15666         set find
```

Surprising!

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed reply. I edited my question: See###################################### AFTER the very helpful...THANKS @ravenspoint !

Answer (score 0):

To make @ravenspoint's suggestion concrete, I'd flip it around a bit:

- LOOP over waypoints, creating vertices for each *unseen* coordinate, storing a mapping point→vertex_descriptor.
- LOOP over linestrings, looking up the previously mapped vertices

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b702fe4eddca1cb)**

```
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace json = boost::json;
using json::value_from;

using coord = double;

struct point {
    coord x, y;

    auto operator<=>(point const&) const = default;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, point const& p) {
        return os << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << ")";
    }

    friend void tag_invoke(json::value_from_tag, json::value& jv, point const& p) {
        jv = {value_from(p.x), value_from(p.y)};
    }
    friend point tag_invoke(json::value_to_tag<point>, json::value const& jv) {
        auto& arr = jv.as_array();
        return {arr[0].as_double(), arr[1].as_double()};
    }
};

using linestring = std::vector<point>;
struct feature {
    intmax_t   id;
    linestring geom;

    friend void tag_invoke(json::value_from_tag, json::value& jv, feature const& f) {
        jv = {{"type", "Feature"},
              {"properties", {"id", f.id}},
              {
                  "geometry",
                  {
                      {"type", "LineString"},
                      {"coordinates", value_from(f.geom)},
                  },
              }};
    }
    friend feature tag_invoke(json::value_to_tag<feature>, json::value const& jv) {
        assert(jv.at("type") == "Feature");
        auto& props = jv.at("properties").as_object();
        auto& geom  = jv.at("geometry").as_object();
        assert(geom.at("type") == "LineString");

        return {
            props.at("id").as_int64(),
            json::value_to<linestring>(geom.at("coordinates")),
        };
    }
};
using features = std::vector<feature>;

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
struct Legs {
    int    id;
    double distance;
};

using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
                                point, Legs>;
using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
using E = G::edge_descriptor;

int main() {
    auto ff = value_to<features>(json::parse(R"([
        {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"id": 1}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 147.0, -4.8 ], [ 141.0, -2.0 ] ]}},
        {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"id": 2}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 152.6, -5.2 ], [ 152.05, -3.8 ], [ 147.0, -4.8 ] ] } },
        {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"id": 3}, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 147.0, -4.8 ], [ 144.73, 0.0 ] ] } }
    ])"));

    G                  g;
    std::map<point, V> mapping;

    // create a mapping for all vertices
    for (auto& f : ff)
        for (auto& p : f.geom)
            if (auto it = mapping.find(p); it == mapping.end())
                mapping.emplace(p, add_vertex(p, g));

    int next_edge_id = 0;

    for (auto& f : ff) {
        auto waypoints = boost::make_iterator_range(f.geom);
        if (waypoints.empty())
            continue;

        V s = mapping.at(waypoints.front()), t;

        for (; waypoints.pop_front(), !waypoints.empty(); s = t) {
            t = mapping.at(waypoints.front());

            auto dx = g[t].x- g[s].x;
            auto dy = g[t].y- g[s].y;

            add_edge(s, t, Legs{next_edge_id++, sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)}, g);
        }
    }

    print_graph(g, get(boost::vertex_bundle, g));
}
```

Prints

```
(147,-4.8) <--> (141,-2) (152.05,-3.8) (144.73,0) 
(141,-2) <--> (147,-4.8) 
(152.6,-5.2) <--> (152.05,-3.8) 
(152.05,-3.8) <--> (152.6,-5.2) (147,-4.8) 
(144.73,0) <--> (147,-4.8)
```

### CAVEAT

Keep in mind floating point inexactness. You might want to implement `operator<` differently for `point` so that Very Close Points(TM) may be treated as identical.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed reply. I edited my question: See###################################### AFTER the very helpful...THANKS @sehe !

Comment: You indeed need to implement `operator<` like I hinted in my CAVEAT. Here's how to do it in my answer code: I changed the input to use a "close" match like `[ 147.0, -4.8 ]` and `[ 147.0001, -4.79999 ]` and if you make EPSILON large enough it will merge them as one unique node: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/452041398b9e46f6 Using a much smaller EPSILON treats them separately: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc55a69e5861bbb0